Do Manhattan Project and Apollo Program count for Culture bonuses?
In particular, the Aesthetics policy "Flourishing of the Arts" gives this bonus:

Culture increased by 33% in all cities which have built a World Wonder.

Do Manhattan Project and Apollo Program count for the above and any other similar bonuses? I ask because when built, Manhattan Project and Apollo Program do not appear under the city's wonders.
